# Send pdf as an attachment in email

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, email, visual-studio-2005

My current application send an .rtf in an attachement. I wish to send pdf instead of that.
Where in my code I should modify the same?

Below is my code

```
        RichTextBox rtbReport = new RichTextBox();   //Creating instance of Richtextbox
        AppResult objResult = null;                  //Object of Class
        frmExaminationReport objReport = new frmExaminationReport(examinationID,   ProviderID, PatientID, examType);                        // Object of Class
        AddressBookDataTable dtAddress = null;
        rtbReport.Rtf = objReport.RTF;               // Entire Result is assigned to Richtext box class
         frmMail objMail = new frmMail();            //Object of Mail Class
         string directoryPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Temp"; //Creating directory

         string tempFileName = "Report_" + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() +  DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() + ".rtf";      //Generating Name
            FileStream fsReport = new FileStream(directoryPath + "\\" + tempFileName, FileMode.CreateNew);                            // FileStream
            fsReport.Write(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rtbReport.Rtf), 0, rtbReport.Rtf.Length);                         // Writing
            fsReport.Flush();
            fsReport.Close();
            fsReport.Dispose();
            objMail.MailSubject = examType + " Report";   //Mail Subject
```

Let me know if any inputs needed

Comment: How do you intend to generate this PDF?

Comment: @Darin: All the text that is being generated in RTF Format needs to be generated in PDF, so that the PDF is being sent as an attachment in email

Comment: There's nothing built-in .NET that allows you to generate PDF files. You will need to use a third party library like iTextSharp for example.

Comment: @Darin: How to do the same with iTextSharp? Could you please explain in brief wrt the code that i have attached. Thanks!

Comment: You can't do the same. Your code uses a RichTextBox which is only capable of generating RTF. You will need to conceptually change the way your application is organized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is incomplete or does not make sense (only for me?). [Here is a simple tutorial](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/email/email-attach-aspnet2-csharp.aspx) to send email with attachment.

If you are generating PDF documents using your code then checkout some [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pdf+using+c%23) in SO.

I don't think you can simply change .rtf to .pdf to generate PDF documents.

```
string tempFileName = examType + "Report_" + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() +  DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() + ".rtf";
```

Comment: Thanksfor the comment. The code written does that it creates  an object of richtextbox and dataset in RTF format is given to that object.Now that rtf oject is passed to filestream object. I am aware of email which sends pdf. I also know that changing the extension wont work...